# Dynamically add component inside another component

Tags: angular

I have a Component that sends user input (text) to a service and receives an enriched version of this text. Enriched meaning that some words are enriched with information.
The server gives me the original text and a list of the enriched substrings each with start and end index of the original text, so I can find them in the original text.

Now I want to show the original text with the highlighted phrases as buttons with popover where the additional information is shown.

In Angular 1, I had a directive in which I dynamically created the template iterating over the found phrases and creating a new button for each of them between non-enriched phrases. With $compile(), they were displayed correctly. The button itself was a directive on its own, so the code looked like this:

```
var newButton = angular.element(
      '<special-button ' +
      'enriched="foundPhrases[' + i + ']" ' +
      'title="\'' + original.substring(start, end)) + '\'" ' +
      'position="\'bottom\'"' +
      '></special-button>'
    );
```

So far so good, but I have not found a way on how to dynamically adding Components within text in Angular 2.

I created a component that generates HTML and then appends that with `this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(generated))` to the Component's element. The code that creates `generated` contains the following lines to generated the special button:

```
let button = this.renderer.createElement(el, 'special-button');
button.setAttribute('[enriched]', 'foundPhrases[' + i + ']');
button.setAttribute('[title]', text.substring(start, end));
button.setAttribute('[position]', '\'bottom\'');
```

But these lines are giving the error during runtime:

```
Error: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element':
    '[enriched]' is not a valid attribute name.
```

How can I arbitrarily add my components into another component with data binding?

Comment: Wouldn't this be better resolved with an ngIf directive or ngShow, rather than adding a new element?

Comment: Can you elaborate? The client does not know how many buttons inside the returned text it should render, so a static ngIf is too limited, I think.

Comment: NgIf with a nested ngrepeat to show how many buttons you need?

Comment: But over what do I iterate? It should put the original text into a `p` element and the substrings from the enriched elements should be `button`s.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this somewhat satisfies what you're trying to accomplish. Direct DOM manipulation is not good practice in Angular.

Suppose have an object phrase which includes the original and text that is "enriched"

```
export class Phrase {
    enriched: string;
    original: string;
    constructor (_enriched: string, _original: string, start: int, end: int){
        this.enriched=_enriched;
        this.original=_original.substring(start, end);
    }
}
```

you then have a `enriched-phrases` component that has a template that includes the original text in an ngIf that will be removed after your backend retrieves the enriched text and is stored in array `foundPhrases`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'enriched-phrases'
    template: '<p *ngIf="!foundPhrases.length"/> '+
              '<special-button *ngIf="foundPhrases.length"'+
              ' *ngFor="let phrase of foundPhrases" [phrase]="phrase" '+
              '[position]="\'bottom\'"/>'
})
export class EnrichedPhrasesComponent{
    onGotPhrases(foundPhrases: Array<Phrase>):void {
        this.foundPhrases = foundPhrases;
    }
    foundPhrases: Array<Phrase>;
    orginalText = "original text block";
}
```

And then you have a component for the `special-button` element.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'special-button',
    template: '<p>{{phrase.original}}</p><button>{{phrase.enriched}}</button>'
}

export class EnrichedPhraseDetail{
    @Input()
    phrase: Phrase;
    position: string;

}
```

So the special button component would be populated with the data after it's retrieved and by using the ngFor directive on the special button it would repeat for as many 'phrases' you have.

Note: I haven't really ever used typescript so there might be some syntax problems there, but that is the gist of what I was trying to explain.